# Latin1_General_CI_AS - Using ruby on rails - Ruby ODBC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server-2008, odbc

The default enconding of my Ruby on Rails Application is UTF-8 but my sqlserver database is using Latin1_General_CI_AS.

When i save the data look's like:

```
são = sÃ£o
```

What encoding should i use to make it works fine?

Answer (score 0):

you can specify your sql server's encoding in the `config/database.yml` file

```
production:
  host: ....
  username: ...
  password: ...
  encoding: latin1
```

Comment: good! but i'm using ruby 2.0 default encoding is UTF-8. I need aways to force_encoding?

Comment: as far as i understand it, your rails code will run in utf-8 and your database data will be converted from and to the encoding you specified in the database.yml

Comment: with your solution i'm getting the same problem.. the data is saving wrong format